# Locate RegEx match then extract

Tags: c#, regex, return-value

I am trying to read text from a RichTextBox in order to locate the first occurrence of a matched expression. I would then like to extract the string that satisfies they query so I can use it as a variable. Below is the basic bit of code I have to start of with and build upon.

```
private string returnPostcode()
{
        string[] allLines = rtxtDocViewer.Text.Split('\n');
        string expression =  string expression = "^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([AZa-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) [0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$"            

        foreach (string line in allLines)
        {
            if (Regex.Matches(line, expression, RegexOptions.Count > 0)
            {                    
                //extract and return the string that is found
            }
        }
  }
```

Example of what's contained in the RichTextBox is below. I want to extract **"E12 8SD"** which the above regex should be able to find. Thanks

```
Damon Brown
Flat B University Place
26 Park Square 
London
E12 8SD
Mobile: 1111 22222
Email: dabrown192882@gmail.com  Date of birth: 21/03/1986
Gender: Male
Marital Status: Single
Nationality: English
Summary
I have acquired a multifaceted skill set with experience using several computing platforms.
```

Comment: what will be the condition of extracting `E12 8SD` ?

Comment: start with `E` end with `SD` something like that

Comment: Remove `RegexOptions.Count > 0` and use `IsMatch`

Comment: What exactly is your issue, the RegEx or how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Regex.IsMatch` and remove the `RegexOptions.Count > 0`

```
string[] allLines = s.Split('\n');
string expression = "^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([AZa-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) [0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$";

foreach (string line in allLines)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, expression)) // Regex.IsMatch will check if a string matches the regex
    {                     
        Console.WriteLine(line);         // Print the matched line
    }
}
```

See the [IDEONE Demo](http://ideone.com/oOPjLo)

Quite possible that your text contains CR+LF line breaks. Then, adjust your code as follows:

```
string[] allLines = s.Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/oFdauP)

**UPDATE**

To just extract the code with your regex, you need not split the contents into lines, just use a `Regex.Match` on the whole text:

```
string s = "Damon Brown\nFlat B University Place\n26 Park Square \nLondon\nTW1 1AJ Twickenham    Mobile: +44 (0) 7711223344\nMobile: 1111 22222\nEmail: dabrown192882@gmail.com    Date of birth: 21/03/1986\nGender: Male\nMarital Status: Single\nNationality: English\nSummary\nI have acquired a multifaceted skill set with experience using several computing platforms."; 
string expression = @"(?i)\b(gir 0a{2})|((([a-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([a-z][a-hj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([a-z][0-9][a-z])|([a-z][a-hj-y][0-9]?[a-z])))) [0-9][a-z]{2})\b";
Match res = Regex.Match(s, expression);
if (res.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(res.Value); // = > TW1 1AJ
```

I also removed the uppercase ranges to replace them with a case-insensitive modifier `(?i)`.

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/PEC7Nu).

Comment: The regex doesn't seem to work if the input consists of a single line: http://ideone.com/wXze7K

Comment: @botond.botos: could you provide a sample input? OP input is multiline. However, since it is a RichTextBox text, I think it contains `\r\n` line endings.

Comment: Just saw the updated question with the new input. It works as expected.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes a line might contain more than just the postcode. How do I clean my result to get just the post code part? I guess I'm trying to understand if there's a method of identifying the startIndexOf and endIndexOf of my regex match.

Comment: Try using `\b` instead of `^` and `$` (use `@""` verbatim string literal). I also have just found `[AZa-z]`, but perhaps you meant `[A-Za-z]`? Check [`@"(?i)\b(gir 0[Aa]{2})|((([a-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([a-z][a-hj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([a-z][0-9][a-z])|([a-z][a-hj-y][0-9]?[a-z])))) [0-9][a-z]{2})\b"`](https://regex101.com/r/eU8gH4/1).

Comment: Thanks, that seems quite reliable so far. Just need a way of cleaning the returned string to give me just the postcode. E.g:

Line is: TW1 1AJ Twickenham Mobile: +44 (0) 7711223344

I don't want the entire line returned, just the postcode part.

Comment: I added another snippet showing how to reduce current code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a killer app now!